# Rename multiple header in a fasta file to leave only the numbers

Tags: fasta

I have a fasta file with multiple headers:

```
     >CABITT030000001.1 genome assembly, contig: 1, whole genome shotgun sequence
    
     >CABITT030000002.1 genome assembly, contig: 2, whole genome shotgun sequence

.
.
.
.
```

And I would like to leave only the `1` and `2` either from the `CABITT03000000*.1` or the number after the `contig:` string.

Output:

```
>1
>2
```

I was trying it with sed command, but it doesnt work.

```
sed 's/>.*/>1/' fasta.fa > newfasta.fa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on the example input you provided, this should work:

```sh
sed -e 's/.* contig: \([[:digit:]]\).*/>\1/' fasta.fa
>1
>2
```

Using a character class for the digit (`[[:digit:]]`), and capture groups (`\( \)` and reference that group with `\1` in the replacement).

Comment: And depending on how many digits you need to capture, use quantifiers. E. g. `\{i,j\}`,         *Matches between i and j, inclusive, sequences*. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html